# NotSupportedException caught when trying to create library based on custom template

Tags: development, client-object-model

I am trying to create a library based on custom template type using the following code:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(@"http://website.network/sitecollection/site/"))
            {
                Web web = context.Web;
                context.Load(web);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo;
                List list;

                listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
                listCreationInfo.Title = "MySpecialLibrary";
                listCreationInfo.Description = formName;

                ListTemplate listTemplate = web.ListTemplates.First(listTemp => listTemp.Name == "DocBank library");
                listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
                listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;

                list = web.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

Unfortunately i am getting a NotSupportedException

```
Invalid usage of query execution. The query should be executed by using ExecuteQuery method on the client context object.
```

Has anyone else got this error and fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the above

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(@"http://website.network/sitecollection/site/"))
        {
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo;
            List list;

            listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
            listCreationInfo.Title = "MySpecialLibrary";
            listCreationInfo.Description = formName;

            var listTemplates = context.LoadQuery(web.ListTemplates.Where(listTemp => listTemp.Name == "DocBank library"));
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            ListTemplate listTemplate = listTemplates.First();
            listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
            listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;

            list = web.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```